# Transform a lot of symbolic expression from x^2 or x^3 to pow(x,n)

Tags: c++, regex, matlab, symbolic-math, cmath

I have a lot of symbolic expressions with the power symbol which I want to copy in a C++ program. However they have the power symbol `^` which is not used in C. Any advice for making the change fast? Should I use regular expressions of i can make gcc to see `^` as `pow()`?

Comment: Which tool are you planning to use for the search/replace operation?

Comment: This might help. Write a small infix parser and then take the generated tree and output the equivilant c/c++ code.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37428-converting-and-evaluating-infix-postfix-and-prefix-expressions-in-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be certain not to foul anything up, you'd need a parser that knows when a `^` is actually being used as a power symbol (and not for example in a comment, a string).

But you might get away with a simple regex:

Replace `(\w+)\s*\^\s*(\w+)` with `pow(\1,\2)`.

That should cover most cases and be reasonably safe.

Of course, it will fail if there are more parameters, like in `(a + b) ^ (c + d)` etc. This regex only matches things like `a^b` or `2^3`. It also doesn't match `x^0.5` correctly, so if those may occur, you'd need `([\w.]+)\s*\^\s*([\w.]+)`

Comment: In Matlab all my variables following a specific namin convention so I used something like this in vim %s /\(\w\d\w\)^\(\d\)/pow(\1,\2)
Thanks anyways for all the help